# SQL QUERY to get preceding digits as 0 if the number is not 6 digit

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

If the POSITION_ID is not 6 digit I want the preceding spaces to be 0

For example-

**1102 should be 001102,
304 should be 000302**

For this i used the below query -

```
  select LPAD(REGEXP_REPLACE(position_id,'\D+'),6,'0')  test from dual
```

But this query is adding 2 in front of numbers that are already 6.

For example
**110092 is coming as 211009
345679 is coming as 234567
106698 is coming as 210669**

How to correct the query I have used above

Comment: Maybe [built-in] function [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html#GUID-00DA076D-2468-41AB-A3AC-CC78DBA0D9CB) is appropriate? By the way, did you make a mistake in the example in your question? Why should **304** become **000302** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to get a formatted string from a number in Oracle is `TO_CHAR`. The format to get a six-digit integer is 'FM000000'.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(position_id, 'FM000000') FROM mytable;
```

Docs: [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html), [Number format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-24E16D8D-25E4-4BD3-A38D-CE1399F2897C), [FM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA)

Answer (score 0):

simple lpad should work. Use also ltrim to remove spaces.

```
LPAD(ltrim(rtrim(position_id)),6,'0')
```

Comment: Close, but - did you count parenthesis? Are they all in appropriate places?

Comment: sorry, typo, corrected.

Comment: I wouldn't know, it wasn't me.

Comment: not a problem Sir. Whomever downvoted has their reason but i would like to know what is wrong with the solution.